# Prop looses reactivity if computed (and mapped) first

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am passing `item.value` to a component. This component also passes the value to a child-component.

```
 computedAttributes(){
            return this.item.attributes.map((attribute)=>{
                return new AttributeItem (attribute.id, attribute.name);
            }) // I absolutely need to do this!
}
```

Now I'd like to open a modal on button click and pass the `selectedAttribute`:

```
<div v-for="(attribute, index) in computedAttributes" :key="index">
    <div>
        {{ attribute.name }}
    </div>
    <div>
        <button @click.prevent="editAttribute(attribute)">
            Edit
        </button>
    </div>
</div>

[...]

 editAttribute(attribute){
    this.selectedAttribute = attribute;
    this.modalopen = true;
 },
```

This works fine, the modal opens.

```
<modal v-if="modalopen">
    <AttributeForm :attribute="selectedAttribute"/>
</modal>
```

But if I now edit any value, the main component is not being updated.

If I change the computed attribute to:

```
 computedAttributes(){
            return  this.item.attributes;
            <!--return this.item.attributes.map((attribute)=>{
                return new AttributeItem (attribute.id, attribute.name);
            })-->
}
```

the changes are updated.

So I can see: Mapping `attributes` to `AttributeItem` breaks reactivity. But how can I change this and update the values correctly?

Comment: Could you show your data()  please

Comment: Could you alswell console log in your .map() the current instance and tell us which one is the updated values or not what should be updated and it isn't

Comment: Don't use `index` for the `:key`, use `attribute.id` instead (`:key="attribute.id"`)